# Does Java have an equivalent to ASP.NET MVC's sample site - specifically with authentication?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jakarta-ee, forms-authentication

I'm trying to develop a simple website that employs forms authentication, but I do not want to build the authentication framework from scratch.  ASP.NET MVC provides a great sample website with authentication built in, but I would rather use Java technologies so that I can lower start-up cost by utilizing open source software.  Does Java (any framework) have an equivalent?

Comment: To give an update on this, I decided to use the Play framework for my project and have been very impressed. It is easy to learn, scalable, and fast. The authentication framework provides a bit less than I would have liked - a few methods to override for login/logout, while ASP MVC provides the methods out of the box and database schema for SQL Server. The project did not require all the functionality of ASP MVC so it was no problem to build the models objects for users, permissions, and groups, and then write simple auth methods. This was mid 2011 though so the module may be updated now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a Java based, clean, bloat-free MVC web framework, take a look at Play:

http://www.playframework.org/

For authentication, take a look at this link:

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1/guide8

The above page is part of the Play framework [tutorial](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1/guide1):

> In this tutorial you will learn the Play framework by coding a real web application, from start to finish. In this application, we will try to use everything you would need in a real project, while introducing good practices for Play application development.

But, by the way, ASP.NET MVC *is* [open source](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/01/aspnetmvc-open-source.aspx)... And you always have the option of using it with [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) (ASP.NET MVC is compatible with it) and Linux. So you can have a complete open-sourced solution based upon it - and without learning a whole new environment.

Comment: Thanks rsenna.  Play seems to be exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Nathan Murray: yes, Play seems to be very cool. And some people is using it with [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/25)... Which is **way** cooler. :-) If you're interested about it, see [this](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1/scala).